# Ensuring modules (tkinter specifically) are imported when importing classes from files

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm hoping to have the following code in its own file (view.py) in a MVC pattern.  I'll have a controller that initializes the object and then calls the main function:

```
from view import GUI
gui = GUI()
gui.main()
```

And then the GUI class ensures that tkinter is properly imported so that it can draw the gui.  As it stands right now, attempting to run the controller code results in the following error:

```
> python controller.py
trying to load Tkinter
loading Tkinter failed, trying tkinter instead
Loading gui
main method
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "controller.py", line 9, in <module>
    gui.main()
  File "[...]\view.py", l
ine 31, in main
    self.root = TK.Tk()
NameError: name 'TK' is not defined
```

Here's view.py:

```
class GUI:
    #import Tkinter # no underscore, uppercase 'T' for versions prior to V3.0
    #import tkinter # no underscore, lowercase 't' for V3.0 and later
    try:
        print("trying to load Tkinter")
        TK = __import__(Tkinter)
    except:
        print("loading Tkinter failed, trying tkinter instead")
        TK = __import__("tkinter")
    #from tkinter import N, S, E, W, END


    def __init__(self):
        print("Loading gui")

    def main(self):
        print("main method")
        # Tk root widget: window with titlebar, etc
        self.root = TK.Tk()

        # Tk buttons frame (left hand side)
        buttonsFrame = TK.Frame(self.root)
        buttonsFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=TK.N+TK.S+TK.E+TK.W)

        # Tk buttons:
        self.buttonLoad = TK.Button(buttonsFrame, text="Load Recipes", command=self.actionLoad)
        #more buttons
        self.buttonLoad.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=TK.N+TK.S+TK.E+TK.W)
        #loading more buttons

        self.root.mainloop()


    def actionLoad(self):
        print("\"Load Recipes\" pressed")
```

I'm worried that part of the issue is due to a lack of understanding of some combination of oop and python philosophy but I'm excited to be schooled in both.

I was hoping that loading tkinter as a class variable rather than as an instance variable would make it easier to address but that doesn't seem to have worked out.

EDIT: Here's the updated view.py that seems to run correctly

```
try:
    print("trying to load Tkinter")
    import Tkinter as TK
    from Tkinter import N, S, E, W, END
except ImportError:
    print("loading Tkinter failed, trying tkinter instead")
    import tkinter as TK
    from tkinter import N, S, E, W, END



class GUI:
    #import Tkinter # no underscore, uppercase 'T' for versions prior to V3.0
    #import tkinter # no underscore, lowercase 't' for V3.0 and later

    #from tkinter import N, S, E, W, END


    def __init__(self):
        print("Loading gui")

    def main(self):
        print("main method")
        # Tk root widget: window with titlebar, etc
        self.root = TK.Tk()

        # Tk buttons frame (left hand side)
        buttonsFrame = TK.Frame(self.root)
        buttonsFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)

        # Tk buttons:
        self.buttonLoad = TK.Button(buttonsFrame, text="Load Recipes", command=self.actionLoad)
        self.buttonAdd = TK.Button(buttonsFrame, text="Add Recipe", command=self.actionAdd)
        self.buttonModify = TK.Button(buttonsFrame, text="Modify Recipe", command=self.actionModify)
        self.buttonRemove = TK.Button(buttonsFrame, text="Remove Recipe", command=self.actionRemove)
        self.buttonQuit = TK.Button(buttonsFrame, text="Quit", command=self.actionQuit)
        # have to assign the layout via grid later because .grid doesn't return a type which messes up stuff like .insert()
        self.buttonLoad.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)
        self.buttonAdd.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)
        self.buttonModify.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)
        self.buttonRemove.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)
        self.buttonQuit.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)

        # Tk recipe listbox (b/c of TK.EXTENDED, it supports selection of any combination of entries)
        self.recipeList = TK.Listbox(self.root, selectmode=TK.EXTENDED)
        # have to assign the layout via grid later because .grid doesn't return a type which messes up stuff like .insert()
        self.recipeList.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=N+S+E+W, rowspan=10, columnspan=10)
        # populate listbox
        for option in range(0,5):
            self.recipeList.insert(TK.END, "option " + str(option))





        self.root.mainloop()

    def actionLoad(self):
        print("\"Load Recipes\" pressed")
        return "load"
    def actionAdd(self):
        print("\"Add Recipe\" pressed")
        return "add"
    def actionRemove(self):
        print("\"Remove Recipe\" pressed")
        return "remove"
    def actionModify(self):
        print("\"Modify Recipe\" pressed")
        return "modify"
    def actionQuit(self):
        quit()
```

Comment: Why are you putting that code inside the class instead of just inside the module containing the class?

Comment: I was under the assumption that if I imported the GUI class and the tkinter import code wasn't inside the GUI class, it would be ignored when an instance of the GUI class is created.

Comment: Where did you get that impression?  I don't think that is true.  Also, you don't need to use `__import__` at all.  You could just to `import Tkinter as TK` and catch the error just the same.

Comment: Moving it out of the class definition seems to have done it.  Why does code out side of the class definition get executed run?  Shouldn't only code within the GUI class be executed?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the way imports work in Python.  Look for other questions about that on this site.  When you do  `from view import GUI`, *all* of `view.py` is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your original code throws the `NameError` about '`TK`' not being defined is that you are importing it into a class (static) variable. So, to make your original code work, either:

- Prefix the use of the variable with the class name, by replacing `TK` with `GUI.TK` everywhere it is used (see discussion in the comments on this answer below).
- Or move the `try...except` block outside the class into the module containing the class, by placing it at the top of the `view.py` file (see discussion in the comments on the question).

However, I think you should avoid using [`__import__`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#__import__) (The documentation says "This is an advanced function that is not needed in everyday Python programming"). Try the following:

```
try:
    print("trying to load Tkinter")
    import Tkinter as TK
except ImportError:
    print("loading Tkinter failed, trying tkinter instead")
    import tkinter as TK
```

You can place the above block inside the class like you did earlier (in which case use `GUI.TK` everywhere), or outside the class in the module. I think you should place the import at the top of the file, just like you did in your updated post ([PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) recommends "Imports are always put at the top of the file").

Also note the use of `ImportError`. It is better to catch the specific exception here instead of catching all exceptions (see the "General Error Catching" section in https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions).

Comment: I actually started out using

    "import tkinter as TK"

but was worried that it might not be assigning TK properly.  Switching back didn't seem to deal with the issue.

Comment: Apparently it was necessary to move the code outside of the class definition, as per BrenBarn's suggestion.  I've also implemented the ImportError for more precise error handling.  Thanks!

Comment: @RagingRoosevelt Of course. I just realized that in your code, `TK` is a class (static) variable. So you could keep your existing code, and everywhere you use `TK`, replace it with `GUI.TK`.

Comment: @RagingRoosevelt also, can you edit your post to add quotes to `Tkinter` in `__import__(Tkinter)`?

Comment: I switched back to the "import tkinter as TK" import technique.  That makes sense about using GUI.TK.  My goal when setting it up as a class variable (naively) was to minimize the amount of text necessary to call what I wanted (consider sticky=N vs sticky=GUI.TK.N).  Which approach seems more robust?  If it's better to go with the class variable route, I think I'll do that!

Comment: I think you should place the import at the top of the file, just like you did in your updated post ([PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) recommends "Imports are always put at the top of the file").

Comment: Please mark Neelabh's answer as accepted so other reviewers know that this question has been answered, and so that he gets the reputation credit he deserves.

Comment: FYI, I updated the answer. From the edit summary: "Updated answer to explain the exact error, and the minimum steps needed to solve it. The previous version of the answer included recommendations which aren't strictly required, and wasn't clear on where to place the recommended code block in the source file."